# Querying getOrders() with an array of AmazonOrderIds is giving me all orders in a timespan instead of only the requested IDs

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm using the Selling Partner API to pull order data for historical orders for which I already know the Amazon Order IDs (3-7-7 format). The documentation (https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/orders-api-v0-reference#get-ordersv0orders) indicates I should be able to pass the order ids as AmazonOrderIds and fetch just those records.

The endpoint I'm hitting is `https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/orders/v0/orders`

An example request body looks like the following. The order ID being requested does exist in the time frame indicated. This is in JSON for visualization but it is being converted into an http query string at the time the request is made:

```
{
    "MarketplaceIds":"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP",
    "CreatedAfter":"2023-02-01T00:00:00-08:00",
    "AmazonOrderIds":[
        "333-7777777-7777777"
    ]
}
```

The expected result would be that I should get a response containing a `payload.Orders` array containing a single order data record.

The result I am instead getting back is a 200 OK with full Order payload of 100 orders with a `payload.NextToken` value to continue pulling additional orders from the timespan. Essentially, the endpoint seems to be behaving like the `AmazonOrderIds` array was not even passed.

Any suggestions on why this is being ignored?

PS: I should add that in actual usage, I intend to request batches of multiple order IDs per request and so a the getOrder endpoint (which does give the expected result) is not the correct endpoint for this use case. I only showed my example with a single order as a simple demonstration of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For some parts of the SP-API when it says it expects an array, it just means a comma separated list, so the query string would be like this:

AmazonOrderIds=333-7777777-7777777,444-7777777-7777778